# Trouble with Firefox not sending cookies with ajax call

Tags: ajax, firefox, jersey-1.0

Websphere 7
Java 1.7
Jersey 1.19

I have a page which is sending an ajax call to a REST endpoint within the same web application.  I have a Filter which sets up the session when the user accesses the page.  However, in Firefox, the session is null when I try to access it in the REST endpoint.  I am not having this problem with IE10 or Chrome.  It seems as though Firefox is not sending the tracking cookie when it makes the AJAX call.  That is what I see in Firebug.  My Firefox is set to accept cookies.

```
var firsttest = function() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "rest/test/testmethod1",
        method: "GET"

    });

};


    @GET
    @Path("/testmethod1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testMethod1(@Context HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonGenerationException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException {

        System.out.println("request = " + request);

        if (!isUserReadOnly(request) && !isUserReadWrite(request)) {
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestResponse testResponse = new TestResponse(1, "A");
        return Response.ok(mapper.writeValueAsString(testResponse)).build();
    }

   private boolean isUserReadOnly(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) session.getAttribute("authentication");
        if (authentication == null) {
            System.out.println("authentication null");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(authentication.toString());
        return authentication.isReadOnlyRole();
    }

    private boolean isUserReadWrite(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) session.getAttribute("authentication");
        if (authentication == null) {
            System.out.println("authentication null");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(authentication.toString());
        return authentication.isReadWriteRole();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Comment: That post deals with cross-domain issues which this is not.

Comment: There was other things in that post with setting the cookie to not be https and such or setting wrong domain on the cookie.