# AJAX request in Spring secured web application

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing one application in which I integrated Spring Security successfully and I'm able to login/logout and authorise user based on role.

Now, in same application when I trigger some AJAX `GET` request; it redirects request to login page and return my login page HTML page as response. I understand that my AJAX request is not being authenticated by Spring Security.

Now my question is, how can I trigger authenticated AJAX request so that I can get proper response instead of login page as response?

I've configured Spring Security as below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/forgetPassword").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resetPassword").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/changePassword").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/error/403")
            .and()
        .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
}
```

**Update:** Here are my request headers as asked.

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1496834101340r0.5246134202334098; Idea-6adc618e=45c8074c-a056-43bd-a6bd-2b8e7545231f; optimizelySegments=%7B%223910210135%22%3A%22gc%22%2C%223921780062%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%223922680052%22%3A%22false%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; _ga=GA1.1.304304118.1496834102
Host:localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/QuickBill/invoice/new
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response header for any request after successful login

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Sat, 29 Jul 2017 06:56:07 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Here is my ajax request code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url?clientId='+clientId, 
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
}).done(function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
    console.log(err);
})
}
```

Comment: May I know reason for closing this question?

Comment: You didn't add the session cookie (`JSESSIONID`), so your AJAX call is unauthenticated.

Comment: @dur - If I run my application through ngrok, I can see JSESSIONID cookie in ajax request and I get proper response. But for localhost, it's not going in request.

Comment: I can't see the session cookie in your response, there should be a `set-cookie` response header. However, if you see the cookie in your proxy, it seems to be the same problem like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie.