# Can't access session variable even with session_start()

Tags: php, session-variables

I have trouble accessing my session variable from one page to another. When I access the response from the page that sets the session variable as a regular JSON response, I can confirm that the session variable is being set as desired. However, when I navigate to another page using location.replace, I use PHP session*start()* and cannot access the session variables. I get an empty array for *$*_SESSION, and no value is printed out when the session variable is echoed. I have attached the code for the page that sets the session variable and the page trying to access it. Additionally, I am trying to run the code on an Apache server and access the pages from the exact same domain with all files in the same location.

I have tried following all the PHP rules for session variables I found online, including adding to the first page, which sets the variable

```
session_write_close();
```

And expect that the session variable set is echoed/accessed on the second page.

First Page that sets the session variable:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session


$_SESSION['display_page2'] = "true";
echo "The value of 'display_page2' is: " . $_SESSION['display_page2'];
?>
```

Second Page that is meant to access the session variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); // Check the contents of the session array
echo "The value of 'display_page2' is: " . $_SESSION['display_page2'];
?>
```

AJAX request on third page that calls the first page to set the session variable and redirects to the second page (in the response I am able to verify that the session variable is being set as desired):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
                url: "https://url-to-api",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "firstpage.php",
                        data: { display_page2: true },
                        success: function(response) {
                            alert(response);
                            location.replace("secondpage.php");
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert("Unsuccessful");
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Unsuccessful. Please try password again or request new password.");
                    location.reload();
                },
    });
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @esQmo_ I am using  PHP/5.4.16

Comment: We had similar issue with PHP 5, I remember the session would stop working unexpectedly. Might be a bug?

Comment: That's a really old version of PHP, it's time to upgrade.

Comment: I have updated the version of PHP to 8.2 and I am still having the described problem

Comment: @Dumebi How do you send the session id? Verify that you are using the same session id (for one user) with `var_dump(session_id());`. Is the value changing between the requests?

Comment: I have checked, and I am having two different sessions IDs, although I am on the same browser and accessing the page through a redirect

Comment: @Dumebi How do you send the session id? You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870371/why-is-jquerys-ajax-method-not-sending-my-session-cookie

Comment: @Progman I am not sending the session IDs explicitly. Should I be doing this? I have also viewed the provided post, changed my Ajax method and the headers as suggested and attempted other related suggestions. I, unfortunately, still cannot get the session id to be the same.

Comment: your firstpage and secondpage code seem to work fine on my server. Could I suggest you try going to these pages directly and seeing if this generates you a single session ID? If so, this points to your AJAX code. If not, something odd is happening on your server.

Comment: @Simon, when I access these pages directly in my local PHP server, I get the same session ID as required. How do you suggest I modify my AJAX to fix this not happening on my Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP looks right.

I've not implemented ajax in jQuery before but here is one way to do it with vanilla javascript.

```
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <button onclick="nextPage();">Page 2</button>
    <script>
        // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Define a callback function
        xhttp.onload = function() {
          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

        // Send a request
        xhttp.open("POST", "firstpage.php");
        xhttp.send();
        
        function nextPage() {
            // Create an XMLHttpRequest object
            const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Define a callback function
            xhttp.onload = function() {
              document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }

            // Send a request
            xhttp.open("POST", "secondpage.php");
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```