# Cookie get expire after redirect in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-cookies

I am implementing `Remember Me` functionality, on login page with a `checkbox`.
 When i logged into account cookie created get expire!
*this is my full page code*

**this is my login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using LTS_DAL;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class LTS_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
LTS_DataClassesDataContext dc;
HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie("remme");

public int ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    int val=0;
    dc = new LTS_DataClassesDataContext();
    var query = (from sn in dc.LTS_Login_Masters
                 where sn.LM_Password == password && sn.LM_Username == username
                 select sn).ToList();
    if (query.Count > 0)
    {
        var qu = (from sn in dc.LTS_Employee_Masters
                  where sn.Emp_ID == query[0].LM_Emp_ID
                  select sn).ToList();
        LTS_Session.Current.loginDetail = qu[0];
        c.Values.Add("Emp_Name", qu[0].Emp_FName);
        c.Values.Add("Emp_ID", qu[0].Emp_ID.ToString());
        Session["LoggedIn"] = "Yes";

        var appoff = (from sn in dc.LTS_Approval_Officers
                      where sn.Officer_1 == query[0].LM_Emp_ID || sn.Officer_2 == query[0].LM_Emp_ID
                      select sn).ToList();

        if (appoff.Count() != 0)
        {
            val = 2;            
        }
        else
        {
            val = 1;
        }
    }
        return val;
}

protected void AuthenticateUser(string UserName, string Password, bool RememberMeSet)
{
    string strRedirect = "";

    int val = ValidateUser(UserName, Password);
    if (val == 1 || val == 2)
    {
        if (RememberMeSet)
        {
            //clear any other tickets that are already in the response
            Response.Cookies.Clear();
            //set the new expiry date - to thirty days from now
            DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
            //create a new forms auth ticket
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, UserName, DateTime.Now, expiryDate, true, String.Empty);
            //encrypt the ticket
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            //create a new authentication cookie - and set its expiration date
            HttpCookie authenticationCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            authenticationCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            //add the cookie to the response.
            Response.Cookies.Add(authenticationCookie);

            c.Values.Add("UserName", UserName);
            c.Values.Add("Password", Password);
            Response.Cookies["remme"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
        }
        if (val == 1)
        {
            strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
            if (strRedirect == null)
                strRedirect = "UserHomePage.aspx";
        }
        else if (val == 2)
        {
            c.Values.Add("App_Off1", "y");
            strRedirect = "~/Admin/DashBoard/DashBoard.aspx";
        }
        Response.Cookies.Add(c);
        Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Invalid Login";
    }
}
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthenticateUser(txtusname.Text, txtpass.Text, chkRemme.Checked);
}
}
```

*this is my second page where i am calling the cookie* 
**Dashboard.aspx.cs** this is my home page after login.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using LTS_BAL;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Admin_DashBoard_DashBoard : System.Web.UI.Page
{
Dash_Board em = new Dash_Board();
HttpCookie ck;
static int Leave_ID;
static int Emp_ID;

protected void grdPenLeave_PageIndexChanging(object sender,
GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdPenLeave.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrdPenLeave();
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ck = Request.Cookies.Get("remme");
        Authorize();
    }
}

protected void Authorize()
{
    string strRedirect;
    if (Request.Cookies["remme"] != null)
    {
        if (Session["LoggedIn"] == null)
        {
            //if (Request.Cookies["remme"].Name[3] != null)
            if (ck["App_Off1"] != null)
            {
                strRedirect = "~/Admin/DashBoard/DashBoard.aspx";
                Emp_ID = int.Parse(ck["Emp_ID"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
                if (strRedirect == null)
                    strRedirect = "UserHomePage.aspx";
            }
            Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["LoggedIn"] = "Yes";
            if (ck["Emp_Name"] != null)
            {
                lblHeadUserName.Text = "Hello " + ck["Emp_Name"].ToString();
                Emp_ID = int.Parse(ck["Emp_ID"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    else if (Request.Cookies["remme"] == null && Session["LoggedIn"] == null)
    {
        strRedirect = "~/LTS_Login.aspx";
        Response.Redirect(strRedirect);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please provide full code - where c is declared and what type exactly is c

Comment: you are checking the cookie after the redirect ?

Comment: @Parv Sharma code has updated!

Comment: @V4Vendetta, yes. I am. chk the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if you are really checking the Cookie after redirecting to `Response.Redirect("~/Admin/UserHomePage.aspx");`? So I did a small example demonstrating on how to set and retrieve a cookie..

**ASPX page**

```
<div>
    Cookie:
    <br />
    <asp:Literal ID="litCookie" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSetCookie" runat="server" Text="Set Cookie" 
        onclick="btnSetCookie_Click"  />
</div>
```

**code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
    if (c != null)
        litCookie.Text = string.Format("Username {0} Passwort {1}", c["username"], c["password"]);
    else
        litCookie.Text = "No Cookie \"myCookie\" found!";
}
protected void btnSetCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie c = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
    c.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
    c.Values.Add("username", "franz");
    c.Values.Add("password", "1234");
    Response.Cookies.Add(c);

    litCookie.Text = "Cookie added! Please reload to load cookie";
    // or redirect manually
    // Response.Redirect("YOURSITE.aspx");
}
```

Comment: In Login.aspx.cs(after i click remember 
me checkbox) even if the cookie 
expiration is set to:
`Response.Cookies["remme"].Expires = 
DateTime.Now.AddHours(1); `

When after redirect i access the cookie 
in Dashboard.aspx.cs in:
`ck = Request.Cookies.Get("remme");`
Comments:
ck is not null but when i close the 
browser and restart the Dashboard.aspx 
page 
`ck = Request.Cookies.Get("remme");`  is 
null and it again takes me to the login 
page

Comment: I am not quite sure if your cookie is created over all.. Pls check out this question [cookies on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost) and comment if this solves your problem!