# How to NOT use http://localhost when testing in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

(Please note: I am not allowed by the submission process to use the URL "...l o c a l h o s t" etc so I hope my Q is understood.)

In order to test cookies javascript code one needs to set up a non ...localhost... server.

I used these instructions...
[Why won't asp.net create cookies in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost)

but I cannot work out how to set up step 2....

I changed my hosts file and am using '.livesite.com' in cookies code.

However when I run a page (F5) ...localhost... is being used.

Do I need to set an option in my VS2010? I have googled but cannot find.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your local IIS web server and you can use your computer name as the URL instead of localhost. To change the option in VS 2010 right click on the project and select properties. In the web tab select "Use Local IIS web server". Specify your computer name plus the virtual directory you want to run your application in.

Comment: Thanksbut totally bamboozled (new to VS)

Comment: Thanks but totally bamboozled (new to VS).

In Solution Explorer I right-clciked the first line C:\...\etc
I opened Properties Window
There is no Web tab nor "Use Local IIS web server". There is a Virtual path setting.

Comment: oh...it seems I do not have a project merely a website. Off I go back to my books and try to work out the differences and the need for a project.