# Chrome doesn't support cookies for locals

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am using following code to set cookie at localhost:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {
    if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
        //it is still within the day
        //hide the div
        $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').hide();
    } else {
        //either cookie already expired, or user never visit the site
        //create the cookie
        $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1 });

        //and display the div
        $('#shownOnlyOnceADay').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

It is working fine on Firefox but not on Chrome. I did google and found

> Chrome doesn't support cookies for locals

but it seems doubtful to me. Can any one guide me & explain me why Chrome does not support cookies at localhost.

Comment: Where did you find that Chrome doesn't support cookies on localhost?

Comment: @robertc: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211#c29

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't asp.net create cookies in localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost)