# Cookie appears in response header, but not set in chrome / firefox

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, mozilla

I'm setting a cookie on my localhost domain and followed everything pointed in the highest ranked questions here in SO : [set-cookie : Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain) and [Why won't asp.net create cookies in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost)

```
tkn=2DH1hWlhOrl1Ty5qsYYyHKXZlfTOac; 
Domain=.localyyyyyyyy.com; 
Expires=mar., 21 avr. 2015 20:36:48 WEST; 
Path=/; 
HttpOnly
```

and I have bind on /etc/hosts `127.0.0.1   to    dev.localyyyyyyyy.com`

I can see the response header with the cookie but I can't see it stored in Chrome nor Firefox.
[image: response-headers]

and on the cookies tab, nothing : [image]

Do you guys, have any idea about this ?

Thanks,

Comment: For one, your "expires" bit seems localised (both language and time zone) and browser expects a fixed format, please adjust to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: @Copernic So what was the problem..! Did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi, have you solved the problem? I'm facing the same problem as yours.. :(