# Slim setCookies not working

Tags: cookies, localhost, slim

I try to get the `$app->setCookies()` and `$app->getCookies()` to work.

So heres my `$app` config:

```php
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'view' => new \Slim\Views\Twig(),
    'debug' => true,
    'cookies.encrypt' => false,              // <= so it is no encrypt bug
    'cookies.secret_key' => '6yxwi8fg4tr72', // <= just random digits
    'cookies.cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cookies.cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
));
```

The Middleware that I added is just injecting some variables. [No SessionMiddleware]

```php
$app->get('/login',function () use ($app) {
    $app->setCookie('admin', true);
    $app->redirectTo('home');
});
```

According to the Answer on: [Why won't asp.net create cookies in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost) edited the /etc/hosts file.

However no matter what I do, whenever `$app->setCookies()` is called, I retrieve only a blank page. If I comment it out, I get redirected to my homepage. No errors are thrown as well.

Comment: What is the status code of the page when it is blank?

Comment: The response even in html is empty. So no 404 or anything like that. Btw i use the firefox browser.

Comment: Header should contain a status code. Try to use a console in your browser and go in the Network tab. You'll see the status code.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I use the composer for loading slim do I need an extra Module for Slim2 to get cookies working?

Comment: What version of Slim are you using?

Comment: Thanks David Pastore for making me look in my composer.json file to see an unneeded dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into my composer.json settings and found a dependency on `doctrine/cache` what seemed to interfere.

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "pimple/pimple": "3.*",
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*",
        "twig/twig": "1.18.*",
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["website/", "generated-conf/"]
    }
}
```

Now with these settings the cookies are working fine.