# Using Forms Authentication with localhost with WebForms

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, webforms, forms-authentication

I am working on an old application that uses Forms Authentication and I'm trying to get it working locally as a web site in Visual Studio 2012. It seems to run OK using the internal debugger on `http://localhost:54006/`. Images, html, etc are served out. Unfortunately with login, I think there is some cookie issue that is preventing it from thinking I'm logged in. I noted that in the `web.config` there was the wrong `domain` set. I've changed that to read localhost, but I still haven't had any luck.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="/" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="480" name=".ASPXAUTH_ADD" domain=".localhost" enableCrossAppRedirects="true">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
```

Does that setting look okay for running this from Visual Studio at `http://localhost:54006/`? It does not complain about a bad username or password. It works in production with a different domain attribute set. Is the correct domain attribute for localhost ".localhost"?

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

**EDIT**: I was able to get it working by simply *removing* the domain attribute rather than trying to set it. Why does that work?

Answer (score 0):

"Gets the value of the domain of the forms-authentication cookie." "The default value is the current domain."

the [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiedomain%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives the value "contoso.com."

looks like a good top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost) (more detail).
another (similar) answer [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8d44fb/how-to-access-the-site-using-domain-name-instead-of-localhos/).