# C# .Net cookie has value in production but not on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I have a cookie that holds a tmp file name for backend processing.

```
    try {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("TargetExcelFile") {
            Name = "TargetExcelFile",
            Path = "/",
            Secure = true,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d),
            Value = file
        };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Create file cookie failed: " + e.Message);
    }
```

In production it works fine but on `localhost` the value in the browser is blank.  I can set breakpoints and see that the cookie has a value in both cases at the `Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);` line.

When run on `localhost` the cookie is created but with no value in the browser.

I had the thought that the `Secure` flag might be an issue on `localhost` so I did the following:

```
    try {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("TargetExcelFile") {
            Name = "TargetExcelFile",
            Path = "/",
#if DEBUG
            Secure = false,
#else
            Secure = true,
#endif
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d),
            Value = file
        };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Create file cookie failed: " + e.Message);
    }
```

... it didn't help.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the domain attribute on the `httpCookies` node is set to a specific domain. Remove the domain name for development:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

This settings is in the `web.config` file under `system.web`.

See more info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390219/why-wont-asp-net-create-cookies-in-localhost).

Comment: Thanks David!  Worked like a charm.